# change Active Directory LDAP user or group permissions via script

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, active-directory, ldap

I Have a question for you

I want to create a script to configure a fresh install of Active directory Server 2008 R2.
Basically,
Create OU.
Create some user accounts and groups in the OU
(Managed to handle up to here )
And then…
Add users and groups to another group while setting their permissions on that group object.

Don’t have a clue of how to do that, tried to create new rule, and access the security object, nothing worked for me yet.

I'm using  C# but If you have a lead for me that uses PowerShell, that would be great too.

Thank you very much,

Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the AD cmdlets for this (everything you want to do is in the documentation). I would also refer from installing 2008R2 for a new domain since this product is already out of mainstream support (it has been succeeded with 3 new versions, 2012, 2012R2 and the new one that will be on the VL portal in a few days)

Comment: ill note that about the server, can you link me for a guide to cmdlets in that field ? thanks